# Is it possible to get files from driveapp if you already know the full path name?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a set file structure in google drive and knowing the full path name I'd like to go straight to that folder to pull files as opposed to going through each level? Is that possible?

Currently I am doing this:

```
function getFiles() {
  var dApp = DriveApp;
  var vfolder = dApp.getFoldersByName("video").next();
  var yearfolder = vfolder.getFoldersByName("2018").next();
  var gamefolder = yearfolder.getFoldersByName("game1").next();
  var folderez = gamefolder.getFoldersByName("ez").next();
  var ezIter = folderez.getFiles();
}
```

But I'd like to do something more like

```
 var dApp = DriveApp;
 var folder = dApp.getFoldersByName("video/2018/game1/ez").next();
 var ezIter = folderez.getFiles();
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `DriveApp.getFoldersByName("ez")` doesn't work? Consider also that there is no such thing as file path hierarchy in Google Drive - what matters is the parent file ID. An entity in Google Drive may have multiple parent IDs.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the folder's id locally, then you can use [`DriveApp.getFolderById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderById(String)) to reference that folder directly as follows:

```
var somefolderId = "[FOLDER_ID]";

var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(somefolderId);
var files = folder.getFiles();
```

You can retrieve a folder's id by calling [`getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getId()) on the folder. Or you can grab it from the Google Drive GUI via the context menu (right-click on the folder and select `Get shareable link`).

Comment: My folders are sorted by year 1998-2019, and then they have subfolder game0-game15 and those have subfolders sl (sideline) and ez (endzone).  So I could get do a getId() for each year and then go to the subfolders from there or have a table with the folder ID for each of my bottom level or game folder?  What do you think would be more efficient?